# iOS Click/Drag event in other apps

Tags: ios, swift, macros, user-interaction, cross-application

I need an app that can create `click/drag macros` to interact with other apps or the system in general.

From searching on the `app store`, and online, the closest thing I could find was autotouch, which could be used to simulate rapid clicking. However, this isn't nearly close enough to what I need.
Thus, I tried to look up the relevant functions so I could write the app myself. Unfortunately, I could not find any prior discussion of this problem.

A good description of the functionality I am looking for is the way TestComplete's [Drag method](https://support.smartbear.com/testcomplete/docs/reference/test-objects/controls/mobile/android/device/drag.html) works.

Unless I missed something, there's no straightforward way to create `click/swipe/drag macros` that work across apps in iOS.

So are there any "hacky" methods to accomplish this task?

**Example usages:**
create a macro for navigating between menus in another app
clicking very specific spots in a very specific sequence in another app
quickly change settings/configuration in another app

Comment: Not possible with an App Store app.

Comment: Are there existing libraries for this for rooted/"jailbroken" systems?

Answer (score 1):

Apps submitted to the iOS App Store are required to be sandboxed, meaning each app exists in its own isolated environment in the file system and is only allowed to interact with the outside system via approved public APIs defined in Apple's frameworks. This, of course, is for security reasons, and no Apple frameworks provide the functionality you want. I would also imagine that enabling apps to control other apps via gesture macros is not something Apple is likely to support in the future, given that even system-wide screen-recording apps are currently banned.

Comment: Thanks, that would explain why I couldn't find any "official" apps with such features. I'm still interested if anyone knows of existing libraries that provide this functionality for rooted/"jailbroken" systems.